# How to append string in HTML form

Tags: python, html, django, web

I am new to web development . I am using python django framework for creating my website.I wanted to take username as form Input  and call a URL like reco/username/ . But when I am trying to append  in the username in URL .I   am getting only "/reco/" and user name is not appended in the URL.

This is the code snippet .

```
<form action= "/reco/"+username method="post">
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="{{ current_name }}">
      <input type="submit" value="OK">
      {{ 
 </form>
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.How can append input field into the url.

Comment: then no need for the PHP tag? yes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use **javascript** in the HTML, something like this:

```
<script>
function myOnSubmit(myForm)
{
  myForm.action =  "/reco/" + myForm.username.value;
  return true
}
</script>

<form onSubmit="return myOnSubmit(this)" action="/reco/" method="post">
      <label for="username">Username: </label>
      <input id="username" type="text" name="username" value="{{ current_name }}">
      <input type="submit" value="OK">

</form>
```